# text-box conditional formatting dependent on other text-boxes

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

i have a bunch of textboxes on a report whose conditional formatting references the record

i have another textbox on the report that references the `TEXT` in the textboxes mentioned above (which is dependent on the record set)

the question is, will i have an accurate evaluation of a conditional formatting on a textbox that is referencing other textboxes whose conditional formatting depends on the dataset even though they are all opening on the report at the same time.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description was challenging.  See if I got it right.

txtA is bound to a field in your form's record source.  Another text box, txtB, has an expression which references the value in txtA as its control source.  And you have conditional formatting applied to txtB.

It shouldn't matter whether txtA also has conditional formatting.  Your control source for txtB looks at txtA value, and doesn't care about any conditional formatting on txtA.

That's how I think it should work, but I haven't tested to confirm.